# Performing segue from custom imageView class?

Tags: swift, swift3, segue, swift4, uistoryboardsegue

I create rounded user icons with a custom UIImageView class. I make these image views interaction enabled, so that when a user taps on one of them, it should segue to another view controller.

I can successfully get each users data printed upon tapping an icon, but I keep getting error "no segue with identifier 'confirm'", even tho I have triple checked that that is the correct identifier. Can one not segue this way?

Here is the code to run when an icon is tapped (this is located inside the icon.swift file) I create an instance of the controller to access the segue on tap:

```
  @objc func iconWasTapped() {
    //
    var controller = ConfirmOpponentController()
    print("\(game.playerOne?.username ?? "") VS \(game.playerTwo?.username ?? "")")
    controller.segue()
}
```

Here is the segue method inside the view controller file:

```
  let SEGUE_TO_CONFIRM = "confirm"

  func segue() {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SEGUE_TO_CONFIRM, sender: nil)
}
```

Inside the storyboard, I have controlled dragged and created a push segue, and named it 'confirm'. I did NOT control drag from a button, or an icon. I just linked up the view controllers.

Comment: Your segue code in your VC is fine.  But you need to rethink how your custom view will talk to your view controller.  You can't just write controller = ConfirmOpponentController().  That instantiates a new controller, unconnected to any storyboard or screen.  That's why you get the error -- your newly allocated controller has no segues because its not even on a storyboard.  You need to figure out how to get a reference to THE view controller instance which is already displaying your custom view.  There's a few ways to do it ... you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think in easy way you can Add a tap gesture recognizer to the image view, set the action to be a segue going to your destination view controller, add an if statement to your "prepareForSegue" function.